# Adding background color in TurnJS

Tags: javascript, html, css, turnjs

I have experienced problem I have never faced before and even googling it did not help.
I have basic code from the official page of script **TurnJS**, which is the problem I have with.

```
<div id="flipbook">
<div class="hard"> Turn.js </div>
<div class="hard"></div>
<div> Page 1 </div>
<div> Page 2 </div>
<div> Page 3 </div>
<div> Page 4 </div>
<div class="hard"></div>
<div class="hard"></div>
```

This works as it should but is has transparent background so when you have any text on pages it overlays themselves so you cannot read the text properly.

When I add

```
#flipbook div{
    background: white;
}
```

It somehow breaks. Pages skew when hovered etc. 
I cannot insert a jsfiddle example because the link for turnjs script is not https and I am not allowed to insert http links. And here it shows me error in code.
The skewed page is shown on image below. 
Does someone know how to add a `bg-color`to that **flipbook**?
I would aprreciate any comments.
[image: Skewed page in TurnJS]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add another class to your pages which specifies a background colour:

```
<div id="flipbook">
<div class="hard"> Turn.js </div>
<div class="hard"></div>
<div class="pageStyle"> Page 1 </div>
<div class="pageStyle"> Page 2 </div>
<div class="pageStyle"> Page 3 </div>
...
```

And then specify everything you need in that class. The other method is to load background images for each page. This is generally how a magazine would be created in TurnJS as it's easier to automate.
Although I just went over their docs looking for this (I know it works, I've done it before) and couldn't find much about it.

Comment: I want it as a text book so I cannot load background images but this works fine. So thank you so much for help.